# looping through a deque using a recursive function in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, deque

I am trying to create a recursive function in c++ that takes in a deque of integers as a parameter, loops through each element one by one, and returns the deque. I have found a few previous posts on StackOverflow that do something similar, but I am unable to understand what is happening in their answers. I am relatively new to C++. While it may be far easier and more efficient to do this by using an iterative algorithm, I am required to use recursion (it's an assignment question). Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may add some details to your question, I didn't get what does it mean "*recursively*" in that case

Comment: the function uses recursion

Comment: And should it return the same deque passed as parameter?

Comment: Yes. The reason I am doing this is because I will be modifying this later (so that I can do manipulation like multiplying each element by a constant or squaring each element in the vector and other things). I just want to get this bit working first before going to implement other stuff

Comment: And why do you need recursion for that? It should be more efficient simply use iterative algorithm on the deque, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you don't understand similar things, you won't understand this either. Study recursion first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be something like this

```
deque <int> x;
void Calc (deque <int> d){
    if (d.empty()) return;
    x.push_back(d.front());
    d.pop_front();
    Calc(d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it have to be a Void return type? Isn't it possible to return a deque? instead of void couldn't we have function signature in the form of deque<int> Calc (deque<int> d)? Just curious to know

Comment: yes sure it could return a deque of int or whatever you want but be sure to make the right changes